# Sharing CheckPoint VPN connection

Tags: ubuntu, debian, iptables, vpn, ip-forwarding

Sorry for my english.

I have 2 VirtualBox VM. One with **Debian 8** and the other with **Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS**. Both configured with a bridged network adapter. Both machines have the same MAC an IP address (I never use them simultaneously).

In both VM, I've installed the **CheckPoint VPN Client** (**snx**). In both I can connect to the remote VPN server without problems. When I connect with the remote server a dynamic network interface is up (**tunsnx**). The remote LAN address is **x.x.x.x/24**.

For sharing the VPN connection with the computers of my LAN, I've activated (in both VM) the IP forwarding  (**sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1**) and I've setted the following iptables rule:

**iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s y.y.y.y/24 -o tunsnx -j MASQUERADE**

Also I've added a route to the x.x.x.x/0 network to all the computers i n my LAN:

**route add x.x.x.x mask 255.255.255.0 y.y.y.21** (windows hosts)

**y.y.y.21** is the IP of the VM and **y.y.y.y/24** is my local network address. Making this I can connect to the remote server through the VM from any computer of my local network. All work fine.

I know that all the configurations that I've mentionated here are gone when I reboot the machines. Dont't worry about that.

Now I've update my two VM: from **Debian 8** to **Debian 9** and from **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** to **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS** and I've repeated all the process: install snx program, activate the IP forwarding and set the iptables rules. I can connect to the remote server from the both VM without problems but I can't connect to the remote server from any other machine in my LAN.

I have make some tests. I've installed other NIC in both VM and connect them to another VM in a private network (**z.z.z.z/24**) and I can see that the IP forwarding and the iptables rule are OK. The IP forwarding is working between the **y.y.y.y/24** and **z.z.z.z/24** networks without problems but is not working between the **y.y.y.y/24** and **x.x.x.x/24** networks.

I've searched google for a few days a I've found nothing useful.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use source nat instead, because wrong source ip goes into tunnel while masquarade:
tun_ip=$(ip a | grep tunsnx | grep inet | awk '{print $2;}')

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tunsnx -s y.y.y.y/24 -j SNAT --to $tun_ip